# Library not loaded: @rpath/libblosc.1.dylib

Tags: installation, jupyter-notebook, pytables

I am working in a virtual environment in a Jupyter Notebook trying to install **tables**, and I cannot seem to fix this error. I have spent many hours looking through similar Stack Overflow questions and nothing seems to work. I tried force reinstalling using `pip install -U --force-reinstall --no-binary tables tables` but [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlCc0.png) still appears when I do `import tables`. When I try `pip install git+https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables.git@develop#egg=tables`, I get a different error:

WARNING: Did not find branch or tag 'develop', assuming revision or ref.
Running command git checkout -q develop
error: pathspec 'develop' did not match any file(s) known to git

WARNING: Discarding git+https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables.git@develop#egg=tables. Command errored out with exit status 1: git checkout -q develop Check the logs for full command output.

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tables (unavailable) (from versions: 2.3, 2.3.1, 2.4.0, 3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.2.0rc1, 3.2.0rc2, 3.2.0, 3.2.1.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3, 3.2.3.1, 3.3.0, 3.4.0, 3.4.1, 3.4.2, 3.4.3, 3.4.4, 3.5.1, 3.5.2, 3.6.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tables (unavailable)

I'm not sure what else to do and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try `pip install blosc` (ie [this](https://pypi.org/project/blosc/))? The dylib from blosc (a compression library needed for tables) is missing or misplaced, and this might fix it.  The developers [recommend](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables#installation) installing it seperately.

Comment: Hi @JoshFriedlander thank you so much for writing back! I tried this in my notebook and I tried the run tests command recommended by the developers (python3 -m tables.tests.test_all), and the same error still appears. I moved the blosc library into the tables folder, but the location utilsextension.cpython-39-darwin.so where the error occurs doesn't seem to exist, so if it is still misplaced I am not sure how to fix that

Comment: If you have homebrew installed, maybe try `brew install c-cblosc`? Otherwise sorry, not sure I can help more :( these kinds of errors are usually very finicky and hard to solve remotely. Might be worth creating a new environment and trying to install everything from scratch